# Infix method call in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Whenever I am trying to use infix method call, IntelliJ IDEA adds parentheses after method name.

For example:

```
val xs = List(1,2,3)
```

If I type `xs contai` and then press Enter, IntelliJ IDEA completes this expression as follows:

```
xs contains()
```

but I expect without parentheses:

```
xs contains
```

Is there an option to disable adding parentheses for infix method call?

I use IntelliJ IDEA 12.1 with Scala plugin 0.7.213.

[UPDATED]

The method I want to call is

```
def contains(elem: Any): Boolean
```

from [scala.collection.immutable.List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List)

The complete expression is `xs contains 1`

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option, and there is no plans to add it in the future yet.
Reason is that it's not infix call, what you want, it's postfix call, and after any postfix call you have to use semicolon or extra line feed. Both things are pretty ugly, that's why in Scala 2.10 you will get warning for postfix calls usages.

Comment: Sorry, the expression was not complete and this confused you. This is an infix call of method contains() of 
scala.collection.immutable.List. I updated my question.